# How to get specific data from a list or string

Tags: python, arrays, string, list, slack

I am making multi-image requests but I can't seem to process more than one url at a time so I want to pull all of them and put them in an array or list.

This is where I got stuck trying to do that:

```
def get_img_url_from_response(self, response):
        print(response.content.decode("utf-8"))
        response_list = response.content.decode("utf-8").split('\n')
        print(response_list)
```

The response.content.decode("utf-8") return the info in this format

```
2022-10-14 15:19:44,784 - Crayon - INFO - {"event": "step", "step": 1, "url": null}
2022-10-14 15:19:44,784 - Crayon - INFO - {"event": "step", "step": 2, "url": null}
2022-10-14 15:19:44,785 - Crayon - INFO - {"event": "step", "step": 3, "url": null}
2022-10-14 15:19:44,785 - Crayon - INFO - {"event": "step", "step": 4, "url": null}
2022-10-14 15:19:44,785 - Crayon - INFO - {"event": "step", "step": 5, "url": null}
2022-10-14 15:19:44,785 - Crayon - INFO - {"event": "step", "step": 6, "url": null}
2022-10-14 15:19:44,785 - Crayon - INFO - {"event": "step", "step": 7, "url": null}
2022-10-14 15:19:44,785 - Crayon - INFO - {"event": "step", "step": 8, "url": null}
2022-10-14 15:19:44,785 - Crayon - INFO - {"event": "step", "step": 9, "url": null}
2022-10-14 15:19:44,785 - Crayon - INFO - {"event": "step", "step": 10, "url": null}
2022-10-14 15:19:44,785 - Crayon - INFO - {"event": "result", "url": "./outputs/img-samples/001427.2197993537.png", "seed": 2197993537, "config": {"prompt": "words and things and stuff", "initimg": "", "strength": 0.75, "iterations": "3", "steps": "10", "width": 512, "height": 512, "cfgscale": "7.5", "sampler": "KLMS", "seed": -1, "upscale_level": "", "upscale_strength": 0}}
2022-10-14 15:19:44,785 - Crayon - INFO - {"event": "step", "step": 1, "url": null}
2022-10-14 15:19:44,785 - Crayon - INFO - {"event": "step", "step": 2, "url": null}
2022-10-14 15:19:44,785 - Crayon - INFO - {"event": "step", "step": 3, "url": null}
2022-10-14 15:19:44,785 - Crayon - INFO - {"event": "step", "step": 4, "url": null}
2022-10-14 15:19:44,785 - Crayon - INFO - {"event": "step", "step": 5, "url": null}
2022-10-14 15:19:44,785 - Crayon - INFO - {"event": "step", "step": 6, "url": null}
2022-10-14 15:19:44,785 - Crayon - INFO - {"event": "step", "step": 7, "url": null}
2022-10-14 15:19:44,786 - Crayon - INFO - {"event": "step", "step": 8, "url": null}
2022-10-14 15:19:44,786 - Crayon - INFO - {"event": "step", "step": 9, "url": null}
2022-10-14 15:19:44,786 - Crayon - INFO - {"event": "step", "step": 10, "url": null}
2022-10-14 15:19:44,786 - Crayon - INFO - {"event": "result", "url": "./outputs/img-samples/001427.1596589821.png", "seed": 1596589821, "config": {"prompt": "words and things and stuff", "initimg": "", "strength": 0.75, "iterations": "3", "steps": "10", "width": 512, "height": 512, "cfgscale": "7.5", "sampler": "KLMS", "seed": -1, "upscale_level": "", "upscale_strength": 0}}
2022-10-14 15:19:44,786 - Crayon - INFO - {"event": "step", "step": 1, "url": null}
2022-10-14 15:19:44,786 - Crayon - INFO - {"event": "step", "step": 2, "url": null}
2022-10-14 15:19:44,786 - Crayon - INFO - {"event": "step", "step": 3, "url": null}
2022-10-14 15:19:44,786 - Crayon - INFO - {"event": "step", "step": 4, "url": null}
2022-10-14 15:19:44,786 - Crayon - INFO - {"event": "step", "step": 5, "url": null}
2022-10-14 15:19:44,786 - Crayon - INFO - {"event": "step", "step": 6, "url": null}
2022-10-14 15:19:44,786 - Crayon - INFO - {"event": "step", "step": 7, "url": null}
2022-10-14 15:19:44,786 - Crayon - INFO - {"event": "step", "step": 8, "url": null}
2022-10-14 15:19:44,786 - Crayon - INFO - {"event": "step", "step": 9, "url": null}
2022-10-14 15:19:44,786 - Crayon - INFO - {"event": "step", "step": 10, "url": null}
2022-10-14 15:19:44,786 - Crayon - INFO - {"event": "result", "url": "./outputs/img-samples/001427.3831955726.png", "seed": 3831955726, "config": {"prompt": "words and things and stuff", "initimg": "", "strength": 0.75, "iterations": "3", "steps": "10", "width": 512, "height": 512, "cfgscale": "7.5", "sampler": "KLMS", "seed": -1, "upscale_level": "", "upscale_strength": 0}}
```

Then the response_list splits it at new line and adds it to a list that looks something like this:

```
['{"event": "step", "step": 1, "url": null}', '{"event": "step", "step": 2, "url": null}', '{"event": "step", "step": 3, "url": null}', '{"event": "step", "step": 4, "url": null}', '{"event": "step", "step": 5, "url": null}', '{"event": "step", "step": 6, "url": null}', '{"event": "step", "step": 7, "url": null}', '{"event": "step", "step": 8, "url": null}', '{"event": "step", "step": 9, "url": null}', '{"event": "step", "step": 10, "url": null}', '{"event": "result", "url": "./outputs/img-samples/001427.2197993537.png", "seed": 2197993537, "config": {"prompt": "words and things and stuff", "initimg": "", "strength": 0.75, "iterations": "3", "steps": "10", "width": 512, "height": 512, "cfgscale": "7.5", "sampler": "KLMS", "seed": -1, "upscale_level": "", "upscale_strength": 0}}', '{"event": "step", "step": 1, "url": null}', '{"event": "step", "step": 2, "url": null}', '{"event": "step", "step": 3, "url": null}', '{"event": "step", "step": 4, "url": null}', '{"event": "step", "step": 5, "url": null}', '{"event": "step", "step": 6, "url": null}', '{"event": "step", "step": 7, "url": null}', '{"event": "step", "step": 8, "url": null}', '{"event": "step", "step": 9, "url": null}', '{"event": "step", "step": 10, "url": null}', '{"event": "result", "url": "./outputs/img-samples/001427.1596589821.png", "seed": 1596589821, "config": {"prompt": "words and things and stuff", "initimg": "", "strength": 0.75, "iterations": "3", "steps": "10", "width": 512, "height": 512, "cfgscale": "7.5", "sampler": "KLMS", "seed": -1, "upscale_level": "", "upscale_strength": 0}}', '{"event": "step", "step": 1, "url": null}', '{"event": "step", "step": 2, "url": null}', '{"event": "step", "step": 3, "url": null}', '{"event": "step", "step": 4, "url": null}', '{"event": "step", "step": 5, "url": null}', '{"event": "step", "step": 6, "url": null}', '{"event": "step", "step": 7, "url": null}', '{"event": "step", "step": 8, "url": null}', '{"event": "step", "step": 9, "url": null}', '{"event": "step", "step": 10, "url": null}', '{"event": "result", "url": "./outputs/img-samples/001427.3831955726.png", "seed": 3831955726, "config": {"prompt": "words and things and stuff", "initimg": "", "strength": 0.75, "iterations": "3", "steps": "10", "width": 512, "height": 512, "cfgscale": "7.5", "sampler": "KLMS", "seed": -1, "upscale_level": "", "upscale_strength": 0}}', '']
```

I need to pull only the last event of each image request where 'event' == 'result' and I want to store that whole line in a list or array. If this is a stupid way of grabbing this data I am open to different suggestions as well. How would I go about this?

Answer (score 1):

If `s` holds your input from the question you can try:

```py
import json

out = []
for line in s.splitlines():
    data = json.loads(line.split("-", maxsplit=5)[-1])
    if data.get("event") == "result":
        out.append(data)

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[
    {
        "event": "result",
        "url": "./outputs/img-samples/001427.2197993537.png",
        "seed": 2197993537,
        "config": {
            "prompt": "words and things and stuff",
            "initimg": "",
            "strength": 0.75,
            "iterations": "3",
            "steps": "10",
            "width": 512,
            "height": 512,
            "cfgscale": "7.5",
            "sampler": "KLMS",
            "seed": -1,
            "upscale_level": "",
            "upscale_strength": 0,
        },
    },
    {
        "event": "result",
        "url": "./outputs/img-samples/001427.1596589821.png",
        "seed": 1596589821,
        "config": {
            "prompt": "words and things and stuff",
            "initimg": "",
            "strength": 0.75,
            "iterations": "3",
            "steps": "10",
            "width": 512,
            "height": 512,
            "cfgscale": "7.5",
            "sampler": "KLMS",
            "seed": -1,
            "upscale_level": "",
            "upscale_strength": 0,
        },
    },
    {
        "event": "result",
        "url": "./outputs/img-samples/001427.3831955726.png",
        "seed": 3831955726,
        "config": {
            "prompt": "words and things and stuff",
            "initimg": "",
            "strength": 0.75,
            "iterations": "3",
            "steps": "10",
            "width": 512,
            "height": 512,
            "cfgscale": "7.5",
            "sampler": "KLMS",
            "seed": -1,
            "upscale_level": "",
            "upscale_strength": 0,
        },
    },
]
```

---

EDIT: Ignoring Json parse errors:

```py
import json

out = []
for line in response.text.strip().splitlines():
    try:
        data = json.loads(line.split("-", maxsplit=5)[-1])
    except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:
        continue

    if data.get("event") == "result":
        out.append(data)

print(out)
```

Comment: I tried passing in both the string (response.content.decode("utf-8")) and the list (response_list) and neither worked

Comment: @Sleexic What didn't work? What is the error message?

Comment: for string it's "json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line1 column 2 (char 1)" and for list it's "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'splitlines'. Sorry, I am still relatively new to coding and python, thank you for the help though

Comment: @Sleexic Try `for line in response.text.splitlines():` instead of `for line in s.splitlines():`

Comment: giving the same error as the string. json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line1 column 2 (char 1)

Comment: @Sleexic Then it means you have some other data than you showed in your question at the beginning of the file (maybe newlines). Try to `print(response.text)` and check your data first.

Comment: It just repeats the output of the question above. In the response the timestamp - Crayon - INFO - are all part of a logger and output in the terminal for everything. The only information actually stored in the response is what follows the final '-' and is contained in the {}. I'm not sure if I clarified that well enough in my post

Comment: @Sleexic Try the code I've put in the edit.

Comment: outputs an empty array: "[]"

Comment: @Sleexic Then it means you have some other response text than you shoved in your question.